# Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0

Tags: hive, beeline, hadoop3

> hadoop 3.3.1
> Hive 2.3.9

I use embedded database.
hive-site.xml:

```
  <property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
   <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true</value>
   <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>APP</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>mine</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
```

I have started hiveserver2:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/hive/bin$ hiveserver2
2021-07-09 14:40:56: Starting HiveServer2
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

but when I run `sudo netstat -anop|grep 10000`,it returns nothing.

when I try to connect to hive database using beeline:

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: APP
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: ****
21/07/09 13:16:00 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
```